# ReactiveX C#: Do something when subscription starts

Tags: system.reactive

I've created an `IObservable<>` combination using `CombineLatest()`:

```
IObservable<IList<List<TileItem>>> combination = Observable.CombineLatest(combinations);
```

I need:

```
1. to do something `doSomethingOnFirst()` when first element is reached.
2. to do something `doSomethingOnComplete()` when subscription has completed.
```

Up to now, I've been able to do something when combination is completed. Nevertheless, I don't quite figure out what do I need to do in order to do something when subscription starts...

```
combination
    .Subscribe(
        _ => { },
        _ => { },
        () => this.doSomethingOnCompleted()
    );
```

Any ideas?

Comment: So `combination` can produce multiple values but you only want to act on first `OnNext` and `OnCompleted` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably best to use two subscriptions to accomplish this. When subscribing twice to an observable, it's also best to share a subscription to the source, which can be accomplished with `.Publish().RefCount()`.

```
IEnumerable<IObservable<List<TileItem>>> combinations = null /* using null so I can compile /;
IObservable<IList<List<TileItem>>> combination = Observable.CombineLatest(combinations)
    .Publish()
    .RefCount();

combination.Take(1)
    .Subscribe(_ => doSomethingOnFirst());

combination.Subscribe(_ => { }, _ => {}, () => doSomethingOnCompleted);
```

You can also accomplish the functionality by filtering the observable by index:

```
IObservable<IList<List<TileItem>>> combination = Observable.CombineLatest(combinations)
    .Where((item, i) => i == 0)

combination.Subscribe(_ => doSomethingOnFirst(), _ => {}, () => doSomethingOnCompleted);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid `.Publish().RefCount()` (as this combination can prevent multiple future subscriptions after the initial subscription completes) and just do it this way:

```
combination
    .Select((x, n) => new { x, n })
    .Subscribe(xn =>
    {
        if (xn.n == 0)
        {
            doSomethingOnFirst();
        }
    }, () => doSomethingOnCompleted());
```